# How to do html POST requests to Server with visual basic net

Tags: json, vb.net, post, http-headers

I have been searching all of Stack Overflow but none of the examples seem to work.

I want to do a `POST` request to a server, with additional header information and parameters that look like this

```
{"parameter1": "blabla", "parameter_2": "haha"}
```

How can I do a `POST` request and save the response in a variable?

I can't seem to find a working code no matter where I look, I constantly get errors in VB.net.

Comment: Can you please add the code that is not working to your question?

Comment: http://howtostartprogramming.com/vb-net/vb-net-tutorial-51-httpwebrequest-post-method/

Used the code from there but it don't work. I don't know the command for doing a post request and the command for adding headers. How can I do it

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Reformat for readability, added propper tagging.

Comment: You should really post the error messages...